# Out of order numbering counter

Tags: numbering

I work in a department that writes requirement documents for our workflow. So, a product will have a document created before design that says:

Req 1: product must do A

Req 2: product must do B

Req 3: product must prevent C

Later in the process we modify the requirement document with the customer to adjust any requirements as the design has developed. So, for example we might remove Req 2, and place a new requirement above Req 1 in the document. Our process requires for traceability that each requirement must keep its unique identifier/numbering. So the new requirement added above Req 1 needs to be numbered Req 4. and then Req 1 must jump to Req 3 and Req 2 may never be reused.

The issue ends up being a document with 200+ requirements and multiple authors make manual trackings prone to errors. Is there anyway for Latex to give an out of order auto numbering with this historical memory? Or some process to leave an invisible deleted requirement number in the document? Out of order numbering problem itself seems difficult?

Thank you for any ideas or help!

Comment: don't you want to do manual numbering in this case, more like `\section*{6 something}` than `\section{something}` so adding or deleting a new section doesn't renumber everything?

Comment: You should specifiy why insertion of Req 4 should make Req 1 jump to 3 and Req 2 should not be reused. This is not really clear.

Comment: To omit an item from an enumeration, you could `\long\def\defunct#1\enddefunct{\stepcounter{enumi}}` and in the `enumerate` environment, use `\defunct\item product must do B\enddefunct` to eliminate its use but jump the counter.  However, this technique does not allow a way to number things out of order.

Comment: One might think to define a serial number based on the requirement text, but this would mean that fixing a typo changes the serial number. An external file is necessary anyway.

Comment: I agree with David here, every single thing that automatic numbering does, has negative value for your use case.  Don't use counters for this AT ALL.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility is a two-step approach, separating the writing and printing of the requirements.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{myrequirementcounter}
\setcounter{myrequirementcounter}{0}
\newcommand\newrequirement[2]{%
    \stepcounter{myrequirementcounter}%
    \csedef{myrequirement#1}{\noexpand\item[Req. \themyrequirementcounter] #2}}
\newcommand\printrequirement[1]{%
    \csname myrequirement#1\endcsname}

\begin{document}
\newrequirement{thisone}{This is a requirement}
\newrequirement{another}{This is another requirement}
\newrequirement{hidden}{This is an old requirement}
\newrequirement{added}{This is another new requirement}

\begin{description}
\printrequirement{added}
\printrequirement{thisone}
\printrequirement{another}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

#### Discussion

We define a new counter `myrequirementcounter` to auto-increment the requirement number when new requirements are added.

We define two new commands `\newrequirement` and `\printrequirement`:

- `\newrequirement` takes two arguments: the first is a "label" for storing the requirement, the second is the actual text of the requirement.
- `\printrequirement` takes one argument: the "label" to recall.

Important note: you should make sure the requirements are added to your document via the `\newrequirement` command in (temporal) order. One good way to do it is actually to split the list of requirements into a separate TeX file and make sure that any tool that writes to that TeX file can only append new lines. And you can then `\input` those definitions into your file.

The printing part is taken care of by wrapping the `\printrequirement` commands in a Description List; you can alternatively change the code to wrap it in other environments or do formatting your own way. This is just a proof of concept. The basic idea is that since some of the requirements can be decided to no-longer appear, and perhaps the ordering of the requirements can change, that is the part that requires human interaction and you should let people move around items of that list as they see fit.

#### Possible additions

It is in principle possible to have additional sanity checking code, for example, code that makes sure that every requirement is printed at most once (else issue a warning at compilation), and code that prints all the requirements that have *not* been printed in the document.

Comment: Indeed they do.

Answer (score 3):

With this approach, one must first define labels in the desired numbering sequence, using (as an example) `\defineitems{A B C {pre A}}`.  This means the first item defined (associated with requirement 1) has the label "A" ... the fourth item defined (Requirement 4) has the label "pre A" (the labels must not have spaces, unless grouped).

Then one uses a standard `itemize` environment to present the items that have been defined, in whatever order the list requires.  Since all items must be identified by their label, I have defined `\pitem{}` which takes a mandatory argument of the label.  That label gets retranslated back into a requirement number, as defined earlier in `\defineitems`.

Finally, if one wishes a TeX source-code record of removed items, one may bound defunct items between `\defunct...\enddefunct` in order to skip over them in the list or, alternately, they can be removed completely without consequence, if the paper trail of a previously used item is not required.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{processeditems}
\long\def\defunct#1\enddefunct{}
\newcommand\defineitems[1]{\parseitems #1 \relax<THEEND>}
\def\parseitems#1 #2<THEEND>{%
  \stepcounter{processeditems}%
  \expandafter\xdef\csname processeditem#1\endcsname{\theprocesseditems}%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\parseitems #2<THEEND>\fi%
}
\newcommand\pitem[1]{\item[Req \csname processeditem#1\endcsname:]}
\begin{document}
\defineitems{A B C {pre A}}% PROVIDED IN DESIRED "NUMBERING" SEQUENCE

\begin{itemize}% PROVIDED IN "PRESENTATION" SEQUENCE
\pitem{pre A} product must do D

\pitem{A} product must do A

\defunct\pitem{B} product must do B\enddefunct

\pitem{C} product must prevent C
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great minds -ahem- think alike. :-) (but only alike, and not exactly the same)